# Springboot and threading issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduling

I have a database listener (`DatabaseChangeListener`) in my project which is a thread. I run this thread in my Spring Boot main application like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PocCamelRoutesManagerBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PocCamelRoutesManagerBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private RouteRepository routeRepository;  

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor) {
        return args -> executor.execute(new DatabaseChangeListener(dataSource, routeRepository));
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

}
```

- It runs, but it didn't get change anymore (it worked when I was using
  `DatabaseChangeListener d = new DatabaseChangeListener(); d.start()`), Is it from `Autowired` dependencies?
- When I undeployed my application (from JBoss EAP), the thread still runs. What I have to do stop it?

Comment: The thread is associated with the JVM, not the application.  If you undeploy the app, the thread continues to run on the JBOSS JVM.  You need to shut down the JBOSS JVM to stop the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop it when springboot app is undeployed , in below method in class `PocCamelRoutesManagerBootApplication`

```
@PreDestroy
    public void clear() {

    }
```